# Importing a module after a function is defined

Tags: python

How does the following work in python:

```
def f(num):
    time.sleep(num)
    return num

>>> f(2)
NameError: name 'time' is not defined
>>> import time
>>> f(2)
2
```

How does python "insert" the module into that function, or how does the lookup mechanism work there as to be able to import something after the function is created?

Comment: The lookup is dynamic, though the scope is static. Do you need more details?

Comment: @wjandrea sure -- where does it look it up from?

Comment: See [Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/291978/4518341)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike a compiler, which statically binds names to fixed addresses at compilation time, Python code is executed by an interpreter that resolves names at runtime, so what the name `time` refers to is not resolved by the interpreter until the execution runs into an expression that actually references it, at which point the interpreter will follow the [name resolution](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names) rules to resolve the name into an object.